# Flexcodesdk Picturerbox dispose causing the picturebox invisible

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using flexcode sdk. The problem is that, I would like to know when i put pictureBox1.Dispose (), the picturebox becomes invisible. Is there any ways which I could allow the picturebox stays with is being Dispose. The reasons i dispose is because i am using fingerprint in two seperaate form. Therefore, i have to dispose the fingerprint in the first form to take in second form. Is it possible not disposing it while allow taking fingerprint verification in second form?

```
    private void buttonNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBoxAttendanceVerification.Dispose();
        veringerprint.FPVerificationStop();
        FormLecVerification lectVerification = new FormLecVerification(this);
        lectVerification .ShowDialog();
    }
```

Comment: 1st show us your code so we can suggest adjustments

Comment: thanks sir,  ishown the code